# MySQL - Using COUNT(*) in the WHERE Clause?

Tags: mysql

I want to find all the rows with the same value in. (Or at least a pair)

I.E.

```
James| 19.193.283.19
John| 20.134.232.344
Jack| 19.193.283.19 
Jonny| 19.193.283.19
```

I would want it to return rows James, Jack and Jonny -as more than one row has the IP '19.193.283.19' in it.

I tried doing what the other similar question answered:

```
select *
from `Zombie`
group by `Ip`
having count(*) > 1
order by `Ip` desc
```

But it just returned 1 row with a pair or more of the similar 'Ip' I want every row.

How would I modify the SQL so it returns all indistinct rows?

Comment: Please show your schema.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use an `exists` subquery to find all rows that have a matching row with the same `Ip`:

```
select  *
from    YourTable as yt1
where   exists
        (
        select  *
        from    YourTable as yt2
        where   yt1.name <> yt2.name
                and yt1.Ip = yt2.Ip
        )
```

Sorting by the number of rows with the same `Ip` can be done with a self-join, like:

```
select  yt1.name
,       yt1.Ip
from    YourTable as yt1
join    YourTable as yt2
on      yt1.name <> yt2.name
        and yt1.Ip = yt2.Ip
group by
        yt1.name
,       yt1.Ip
order by
        count(yt2.name) desc
```

Comment: Too quick for me!  I can't write a correlated subquery in under a minute.

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks ALOT! P.S How can I order it so it displays one with most matches first? :)

Comment: The answer has only one table called `YourTable`.  It's aliased twice, once to `yt1` and once to `yt2`.  I've added `as yt1` to the query to make this clearer.  "as" is optional in SQL.

Comment: Quick question, when I try to bring this result into PHP -using while($row == mysql_fetch_array($result)) { most the name fields are the same, -i.e. james james james (same ip = output same name) under $row['Username'] or am I doing the PHP wrong?

Comment: Are there multiple rows with the same username and IP in the original table?

Comment: Fixed now, nvm. used $row[0] etc.

Answer (score 1):

Another way would be to join your table with the subquery you already have used (to find ips existing in more than one row):

```
SELECT t.name
     , t.Ip
FROM 
    YourTable AS t
  JOIN
      ( SELECT Ip
             , COUNT(*) AS cnt
        FROM YourTable
        GROUP BY Ip
        HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
      ) AS td
    ON td.Ip = t.Ip
ORDER BY
       td.cnt DESC
     , t.Ip
     , t.name
```